# Estimating the mean of a Poisson process from data

Tags: estimation, mean, poisson-distribution

My data shows the daily number of logins per person over the last three months.

I am modelling the number of events per person per day as a Poisson process. I am interested in estimating the population parameter $\lambda$ that represents the expected number of logins for any given person on any given day.

Given my data, how should I go about this? For instance, the data for the first customer (`customer_id == 1`) looks as follows:

| customer_id | date | logins |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-05-01 | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-05-02 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | 2023-07-30 | 3 |
| 1 | 2023-07-31 | 1 |

My intuition was to simply calculate the mean of `logins`. However, I saw [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780198/how-do-you-estimate-the-mean-of-a-poisson-distribution-from-data) and made me question if this approach is indeed the correct one.

I can see that my estimator is unbiased, but are there any downsides to simply calculating the mean? What alternatives are there?

Comment: Do you have a Poisson process or not?  If you haven't recorded times between logons, then what about the referenced thread is applicable to your analysis?  Are you perhaps intimating you would be open to estimating counts over longer periods using a Poisson assumption?

Comment: Agree with whuber. The Poisson process is a model for measurements/events which happen at unknown times. But you have a measurement at every day, so it seems you are in a different setting. If not, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if I understand you correctly, customer login (within the same day) is considered the poisson process.

Then, you might want to quickly check see if the time interval between 2 logins follows an exponential distribution. but do you have timestamp per login per customer_id?

on the other hand, if the motivation is just to get the expected number of logins for any given person on any given day. You can first take groupby average by customer_id. then check the distribution of the customer_id level lambdas. and decided whether you want further take an average to get point estimate of the lambda for the population. or give a confidence interval estimate. or even overlay other customer level data (demographics maybe) to get more insights.